# Can you send a message across the network?

Tags: terminal, network, messages

There used to be the ability, perhaps before OS X, to send messages accross the local network, which displayed a popup on the receivers machine with the message. Is this still possible? Or is there another way to send a message to another member of the network?

If this isn't possible, could a text file be sent, with a message, to a recipients Public folder?

Preferably with the terminal.

(I realise there are lots of aps which do messaging, but I was curious if this was possible without installing software or setting up iChat etc)

Comment: Just to be sure, you want to send a message from a Mac to another Mac? Or is there a Windows computer involved? Could you also add which OS versions your machines are using?

Comment: mac to mac. what kind of animal uses windows? not a wildebeest anyway

Answer (score 1):

According to [this metafilter post](http://ask.metafilter.com/108151/Send-Notifications-From-One-Mac-to-the-Next-Over-the-LAN) you can send a message using Applescript (pre-installed on every Mac) and [Growl](http://growl.info) (old version is freely available).
The relevant part is quoted hereunder.

```
tell application "GrowlHelperApp" of machine "eppc://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
register as application "myapp" all notifications {"message"} default notifications {"message"}
notify with name "message" title "title"   description "description" application name "myapp"
end tell
```

Here xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx should be substituted by the IP address of the sender.

Comment: That's interesting, but its a third-party program. Is there something which would work with a base OS X install?